# Can I use Windows 8 with 256 MB of video RAM?

Tags: windows-8, graphics

I Have 256 MB of video RAM in my ACER PC..
These are specific Details of it.

```
Card name: Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)
   Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
      Chip type: Intel(R) GMA 3100
       DAC type: Internal
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_29C2&SUBSYS_26721019&REV_10
 Display Memory: 256 MB
Dedicated Memory: 0 MB
  Shared Memory: 256 MB
   Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
   Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
  Monitor Model: V193HQ
     Monitor Id: ACR006D
    Native Mode: 1366 x 768(p) (59.790Hz)
    Output Type: HD15
    Driver Name: igdumd32.dll
Driver File Version: 8.15.0010.1749 (English)
 Driver Version: 8.15.10.1749
    DDI Version: 9Ex
   Driver Model: WDDM 1.0
```

Can I run Windows 8 smoothly in my PC?

Comment: Please, suggest me.. I don't have much knowledge of Graphics

Comment: Assuming you are already running windows, download and run this tool http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8

Comment: Yaa.. I'm running Win-7.. and going to try this.. Thanks..

Comment: I recently installed **Windows 8 AIO 16** With this check. But it was not able to display my monitor resolution of 1366x768 Properly? why? can u tell me?? If i install and it will happen again then what will i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Why not? Windows 8 only requires a DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver which the one you have already satisfied. Any PC that can run windows Vista or windows 7 can run windows 8 smoothly

Comment: I recently installed **Windows 8 AIO 16** but it was not displaying my monitor resolution of 1366x768? why? can u tell me??

Comment: And Can u suggest link to download Latest and Full version of windows 8

Comment: Wrong resolution isn't a windows problem. It's a driver problem. At install time maybe the driver wasn't available. Just install it later

Comment: Then, I have to try again on it..

Comment: Yupppiii.. I had successfully installed Windows 8 Professional and activated too.. Yes, there was a resolution issue that i solved by updating display driver online after installation. Thank You for support.